# Get Itinerary,passengerreservation as well as price quote for sabre getResarvationRQ

Tags: sabre

Header
passegerReservation
PriceQuote or ItineraryPricing
using the GEtReservationRQ.
below is a sample req which returns only pricequote

```
<ns7:GetReservationRQ xmlns:ns7="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_19" Version="1.19.0">
    <ns7:Locator>IJKZUQ</ns7:Locator>
    <ns7:RequestType>Stateless</ns7:RequestType>
    <ns7:ReturnOptions PriceQuoteServiceVersion="3.2.0">
        <ns7:SubjectAreas>
            <ns7:SubjectArea>PRICE_QUOTE</ns7:SubjectArea>
        </ns7:SubjectAreas>
        <ns7:ViewName>Simple</ns7:ViewName>
        <ns7:ResponseFormat>STL</ns7:ResponseFormat>
    </ns7:ReturnOptions>
</ns7:GetReservationRQ>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `VaDefaultWithPq` for the View parameter to retrieve priced itineraries list along with PNR info:

```xml
<GetReservationRQ Version="1.19.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_19">
    <Locator>XXXXXX</Locator>
    <RequestType>Stateful</RequestType>
    <ReturnOptions>
        <ViewName>VaDefaultWithPq</ViewName>
        <ResponseFormat>STL</ResponseFormat>
    </ReturnOptions>
</GetReservationRQ>
```

Sabre user guide lists other possible view types as well:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Retrieve_Itinerary/resources

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is any other API option for this, which is absolutely maddening. You need to do a separate call to the [DisplayPriceQuote](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/book/display_price_quote) API, I think.

Answer (score 1):

@Anuj,

I use the setup below to get pricingInformation and the priceQuote too!

```
<ns4:GetReservationRQ Version="1.19.0">
    <ns4:Locator>**RECLOC**</ns4:Locator>
    <ns4:RequestType>**Stateful**</ns4:RequestType>
    <ns4:ReturnOptions PriceQuoteServiceVersion="4.0.0">
        <ns4:SubjectAreas>
            <ns4:SubjectArea>**ACTIVE**</ns4:SubjectArea>
            <ns4:SubjectArea>**ANCILLARY**</ns4:SubjectArea>
            <ns4:SubjectArea>**FARE_TYPE**</ns4:SubjectArea>
            <ns4:SubjectArea>**PRICING_INFORMATION**</ns4:SubjectArea>
            <ns4:SubjectArea>**PRICE_QUOTE**</ns4:SubjectArea>
        </ns4:SubjectAreas>
        <ns4:ViewName>**Full**</ns4:ViewName>
        <ns4:ResponseFormat>**STL**</ns4:ResponseFormat>
    </ns4:ReturnOptions>
</ns4:GetReservationRQ>
```

This is the answer that returns ...
[image]